# Would having too many repositories in ubuntu affect it in any way?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I install lots of third party software on my ubuntu system. I wonder if having 50-60 repos added to "software sources" slows down my system in any way? On the other hand, after installing a package, if I remove its source, will it affect anything?

Comment: Oh, and why do you need 60 repos anyway? Are you installing 50 programs that aren't in the official Ubuntu repositories, but have their own Ubuntu-compatible ones?

Answer (score 1):

The only effect many repositories have is that refreshing their meta data and searching within the package index will be a bit slower. The system as a whole should not be affected.

Removing the repository after installing its software means that the software will not be updated. This may easily become a problem, as you will be missing security updates this way.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the comment above, I would be curious as to why you need that many third party repos?

One other minor point to consider is that the third party repos may not be maintained in the same manner as the repos directly from Ubuntu. As stated on Ubuntu.com

> Make sure that all repositories you add in this way have been tested and are known to work on Ubuntu systems. Repositories that are not designed to work with your version of Ubuntu can introduce inconsistencies in your system and might force you to re-install.